# Using ui-router, how can I set a starting page if .otherwise() is pointing to a not-found page?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, state

I want to take the users to a **Page Not Found** page if they put in a bad url, so I have `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/not-found")` set up to handle that.

However, now when I start the app, it starts out on the not-found page, which isn't exactly helpful. **How can I start the application at the home page and then from that point forward, if a user types any bad routes, they'll hit the `.otherwise()`?**

I was looking at `$stateChangeStart`, but that doesn't appear viable. I was doing this

```
if (fromState.name === "" && toState.name !== "not-found") {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go("home");
}
```

thinking that at the entry point of the app, `.name` would be blank and I could redirect to home. However, `toState.name` always equals "not-found", due to the otherwise set-up.

### edit

"use strict";

```
class RoutingConfig {

    static $inject = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider"];

    constructor($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: "components/home/home.html",
                controller: "HomeController",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            })
            .state("not-found", {
                url: "/not-found",
                templateUrl: "components/page-not-found/page-not-found.html"
            });

        var useHome = true;

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(() => {
            if (useHome) {
                useHome = false;
                return "/home";
            }
            return "/not-found";
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try empty route: `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/index');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case, that a first touch should go elsewhere than to "not found", we can use some kind of `.otherwise()` with a **`function`** and some simple *`boolean` switch*:

```
var useHome = true;
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function(){
    if(useHome){
      useHome = false;
      return  "/home";
    }
    return "/notFound";
});
```

Comment: `useHome` is being reset every time I go to a new route, so it's always evaluating as `true`. I added the route structure to my question

Comment: I'm confused. If I go to `/invalidroute`, it's going to go home. How does `/notfound` ever get hit then?

Comment: Well, even based on your edited question.. my answer shows you answer to the question *Using ui-router, how can I set a starting page if .otherwise() is pointing to a not-found page?* ... Just on the app start.. it (only once) goes to home. Later it always goes to not found, if wrong url is provided. I'd say, that my answer is 100 % fit ;) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this scenario in your `run` block. Just add the redirection in your run block. Once, the page is getting loaded, run block will be executed, hence, page will be taken to `home` state.

```
 $state.go("home");
```

Comment: Doing this, the otherwise no longer works because it always hits .go("home") in the run block. So, typing `/badroute` takes me to the home page.

Comment: No, I do not think so. Because otherwise will get priority in case of wrong url. I have verified the same and it works like charm for me.